# How to access form control and form group in angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms, angular-pipe

I would like to `pipe` a form group of a reactive form.

Then I would like to do some checks on this group separate controls.

Here is how I define my form

```
  myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    myFormNameDrop: this.formBuilder.group({
      myName:['',Validators.required],
      myDrop:['era']
    }),    
    style:[''],
    userId:[this.user_id]
  });
```

And this is the `pipe` I try to create

```
this.results = this.myForm.value.myFormNameDrop.valueChanges.pipe(      
  debounceTime(400),
  distinctUntilChanged(),            
  filter(formdata => formdata.myName.length > 0),
  switchMap( formdata => this.shoesService.details(formdata.myName)),
  shareReplay(1)
);//pipe
```

I get two errors. 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined` about the `this.results = this.myForm.value.myFormNameDrop.valueChanges.pipe(`

and VS code shows a warning about the `filter(formdata => formdata.myName.length > 0),` : Property `myName` does not exists on type `'{}'`

How can I access formGroups and controls of formGroups in such cases? I use angular 6

Thanks

Comment: You should try changing `this.myForm.value.myFormNameDrop.valueChanges.pipe(` to `(this.myForm.controls['myFormNameDrop'] as FormGroup).valueChanges.pipe(`. You should subscribe to control change not a value. Value is just plain value of a control.

Comment: @karoluS Hi. I am getting `Module parse failed: Unexpected token ` .I dont know what is wrong at this point

Comment: Where do you get this error?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are not fetching the form controls properly. Use [get()](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get) method on `FormGroup` object to fetch `formControl`

```
this.results = this.myForm.get('myFormNameDrop').valueChanges.pipe(      
  debounceTime(400),
  .........................
);
```

**EDIT :**

To access `myName` you may do it as as follows :

`this.myForm.get('myFormNameDrop').get('myName').value`

---

Also If you are interested in just `myName`, then you could directly watch for `valueChanges` of `myName`, instead of watching `myFormNameDrop`

```
this.results = this.myForm.get('myFormNameDrop').get('myName').valueChanges.pipe(      
  debounceTime(400),
  distinctUntilChanged(),            
  filter((myName) => myName.length > 0),
  switchMap(myName => this.shoesService.details(myName)),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. This worked. Any idea how to access the `myName` of the `myFormNameDrop` in the filter part? I tried something new like ` filter(formdata => formdata.get(myName).value.length > 0),   ` and VScode says "Cannot find myName" . What am I missing? Shouldn't `get` get `myName` ?

Comment: Hi again. If I do this I get `formdata.get is not a function`. Thanks

Comment: I see that `formGroup` `valueChanges` returns its `controls` as a key value pair. So `filter(formdata => formdata.myName.length > 0)` should do it for you.

Comment: Even shorter, the `get` function accepts accessing children using dot notation so to access `myName` it would just be `this.myForm.get('myFormNameDrop.myName').value`

Answer (score 4):

`this.myForm.controls['myFormNameDrop']`

working in template

Answer (score 2):

change this line :

```
this.results = this.myForm.value.myFormNameDrop.valueChanges.pipe( ...
```

to :

```
this.results = this.myForm.controls.myFormNameDrop.valueChanges.pipe( ...
```

Comment: I tried that and I get `ERROR TypeError: You provided '' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`. Also, any idea on how to access the `myName` control of the formGroup in the `filter` part? Thanks